# Regular expression for parse xrandr response

Tags: c++, regex, qt

I need to get display supported resolutions in Qt Application on Ubuntu. I run xrandr command through QProcess and receive display resolutions in a following view:

> Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1366 x 768, maximum 8192 x 8192
>   VGA-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>   LVDS connected primary 1366x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
>
> ```
>  1366x768      59.99*+
>  1280x720      59.86
> ```
>
> etc.

What is the regexp for this case? First, I can remove all the text before the resolutions and then use something like
`^\s+ | [0-9]*x[0-9] | *\s+$`
or

```
^\s+| [0-9]* ([0-9]) * (x) d{3}  |\s+|
```

Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to extract all resolutions? Use `QRegExp("\\d+\\s*x\\s*\\d+")` (see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD5cS9/1))

Comment: Only those, which are listed after the text.

Comment: Aha, so, [`"(?m)^\\s*(\\d+\\s*x\\s*\\d+)"`](https://regex101.com/r/jD5cS9/2). Right?

Comment: Yeah, something like that! Thanks!

Comment: If you precise what exactly you are using (QRegExp or QRegularExpression), I could also post a sample code.

Comment: QRegExp. AFAIK I need to split extracted strings to a QStringList, do I?

Comment: Aha, so, you cannot use the MULTILINE modifier. Just a sec, I will update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to match the resolutions that are the first text on the line, you can use a regular expression like

```
"(?:^|[\r\n]+) *(\\d+ *x *\\d+)"
```

The first non-capturing group `(?:^|[\r\n])` matches  either the beginning of a string or linebreak(s),  `*` matches zero or more whitespaces, and then the second capture group follows, that matches 1+ digits, 0+ spaces, `x`, again 0+ spaces and 1+ digits.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jD5cS9/3)

Sample Qt demo:

```
QRegExp rx("(?:^|[\r\n]+) *(\\d+ *x *\\d+)");
int pos = 0;
while ( (pos = rx.search(text, pos)) != -1 ) 
{
     someFunction(rx.cap(1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I'll try to add it in a Qt Application and see the result of  extraction

Comment: The `(?:^|[\r\n]+) *(\\d+ *x *\\d+)` should match in a multiline string.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much! I don't use Regular Expressions too often, so was needed some help.